# Streaming data and firewall on Chromebook Linux

Tags: linux, python, firewall, iptables, chromebook

I'm trying to use a custom python app that needs to expose a port (5000) on my Google chromebook and it's not working. The python package is python-osc. How do I check if a firewall in Linux is blocking my tablet from receiving streaming data into that port from a device on the same network?

I'm running Chromebook with the newest Debian Linux installed.

The script runs in my terminal and the custom app shows that the package has opened the port, but no data is received. When I posted on the developer forums for that app (below), the only explanation for why this happens is because of a firewall issue.

https://mind-monitor.com/Technical_Manual.php#help_streaming

So far, I’ve tried to open all traffic on iptables, but that hasn’t solved the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! i had to go into developer setting’s and allow port 5000 UDP in linux crostini